# Merge models according to desc order for view - create an Activity page

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, controller

So I have two models `like` and `follow` models, and I want to create an activity page where the user can see his latest activity accordingly. I thought about merging the two models in the view using laravel's `merge` function but I'm lost on how to indicate if a user liked the post or followed a blog.

```
$like= Like::where('user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
$follow = Follow::where('user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
$all = $like->merge($follow);
```

If I use an if statement in the view, it will group the different datas in the view rather than combining them together to make an activity timeline.

If you could help thanks

Comment: If your two model related together, then make a relationship. Then your query like this `$like= Like::with('follow')->where('user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();`

Comment: They aren't  related to each other but they are both needed to create an activity timeline page or view @STA

Comment: Why you need to merge?

Comment: @STA   they want one single list containing multiple different types, ordered by timestamp it would seem

Comment: @lagbox exactly. That's possible right?

Comment: @ObinnaIloeje yes ... if they actually are merged together correctly (which may not be the case since it is an Eloquent Collection, not a Base Collection) you would just `sortBy` or `sortByDesc` the field you want

Comment: Well the merge function isn't working, instead it duplicates the `follow` model data

Comment: I want to be able to merge both databases to create a single activity list sorted by desc order on a view @lagbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge these collections together and order/sort them how you wish. I highly recommend not merging an Eloquent Collection into another Eloquent Collection of different types. Unlike the Base Collection type (`Illuminate\Support\Collection`) which the Eloquent Collection (`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`) extends from it takes into account the models' keys. So if you have 2 collections and any models have the same key in them they will get overwritten. You want to convert one of these collections to a Base Collection then merge in the other one:

```
$merged = $like->toBase()->merge($follow);

$sorted = $merged->sortByDesc('created_at');
```

Or even convert them both to base Collections and merge:

```
$merged = $like->toBase()->merge($follow->toBase());
```